# Programmatically send payments to given account - Paypal android SDK

Tags: android, paypal

Is there any way to make a transaction from my PayPal account to my users PayPal account?
Right now the user can make a transaction to my PayPal account but not the other way around. I would like make it possible to my users to be able to cash out from my account to theirs.

I am using the Android SDK from PayPal, and I can't find any information how to do this. If someone have any knowledge in this, it would be great if one can help me out..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Join PayPal sand box account.
Then you can try like virtual account.

https://www.paypal.com/ipn

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/training/